# How to download a website's source maps?

Tags: firefox, wget, firefox-extensions, curl, firefox-developer-tools

I don't want to write a complete script for this; there must be some simple way to download source maps. By this I mean go to a website (assuming it has source maps) in Firefox, open Developer Tools, then the Debugger pane, then the Sources. I'd like to download the files shown there.

It doesn't seem like there is a way in Firefox's UI to do this. I tried HTTrack, but it didn't download source maps. I tried copying the index request from Firefox's Network panel as cURL, but it just showed the index.html contents in stdout.

I've found [this article](https://pulsesecurity.co.nz/articles/javascript-from-sourcemaps) that leads me to this tool: https://github.com/denandz/sourcemapper, but it only extracts source maps from a single js file at a time.

Comment: The Chrome extension in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46843147 worked.

Comment: Are you sure you want to download the _source maps_ and not the _original files_? [Source maps are cryptic files](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) mapping the code sent to the browser to the original sources.